# Why can't I declare an ArrayList of characters

Tags: java, arraylist, character

Why can't I declare an ArrayList of char, I know the String class exist but it still seem weird I can't do the following piece of code

```
ArrayList<char> foo = new ArrayList<char>();
```

Comment: You need to use the reference type: `Character`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use primitive types as a generic type-parameter; you need to use the wrapper class for `char`, which is [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html):

```
List<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<>(); //Java 7
```

or

```
List<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<Character>(); //Java 5,6
```

This goes for any class that accepts a generic type-parameter. So for example, if you had tried to use `int`, you would get the same error. Instead, you would have had to use `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

its `Character` not `char`

```
List<Character> foo = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

From starting letter you can easily makeout that `char` is not class

Comment: Not sure, mine got down voted to.. I'm wondering if someone is trying to boost their answer?

Comment: @PatrickJAbareII I think so. My answer was downvoted as well. I've upvoted your answers.

Answer (score 3):

Collections do not allow the use of primitive types. You'd encounter this error had you tried any of the primitives, (int, long, double, etc..). Use a primitive wrapper such as Character, to declare the collection.

```
ArrayList<Character> foo = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html),

```
ArrayList<Character> characterList = new ArrayList<Character>();
```